# Unable to run Disable-Mailbox Powershell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to reproduce the following working chunk of Powershell in C#.
We are connecting on an Exchange2010 instance.

```
$ExURI = "http://ExchangeUrl/PowerShell/"

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $ExURI -Authentication Kerberos
$userName = "patatem"

Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber -EA SilentlyContinue | Out-Null

Get-Recipient $userName

Disable-Mailbox -Identity $userName -Confirm:$False
#enable-mailbox -identity $userName -Alias $userName -database "AnExchangeDatabase"

remove-PSSession $Session
```

I've been following the steps referenced here : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/18/access-exchange-online-by-powershell-in-c/

In the following block of code, I get positive results when I call `Get-Mailbox`, `Get-Recipient`.

When calling `Disable-Mailbox`, I get the following error

> The term 'Disable-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Why is it recognizing `Get-Mailbox` but not `Disable-Mailbox`?

(I've tried adding another chunk of code to do the Import session section of Powershell but that didn't change anything.)

```
   public void EnableCommand(string identity, string database)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(identity))
                {
                    using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
                    {
                        runspace.Open();
                        var powershell = PowerShell.Create();

                        var command = new PSCommand();
                        command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
                        command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
                        command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri(Constants.DefaultOutLookUrl));
                        command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos");
                        powershell.Commands = command;

                        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                        var result = powershell.Invoke();
                        if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0 || result.Count != 1)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Fail to establish the connection");
                        }

                        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                        command = new PSCommand();
                        command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
                        command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create("Get-Mailbox"));
                        command.AddParameter("Session", result[0]);
                        powershell.Commands = command;
                        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                        var mailBoxes = powershell.Invoke();

// This will give me a result
                        var returnValue = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (var item in mailBoxes)
                        {
                            returnValue.AppendLine(item.ToString());
                        }


                        // check the other output streams (for example, the error stream)
                        if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                        {
                            returnValue.AppendLine($"{powershell.Streams.Error.Count} errors: ");
                            foreach (var err in powershell.Streams.Error)
                            {
                                returnValue.AppendLine($"{err.ToString()}");
                            }
                        }

// This will also work
                        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                        command = new PSCommand();
                        command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
                        command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create("Get-Recipient SomeEmail"));
                        command.AddParameter("Session", result[0]);
                        powershell.Commands = command;
                        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                        var mailBoxes2 = powershell.Invoke();

                        foreach (var item in mailBoxes2)
                        {
                            returnValue.AppendLine(item.ToString());
                        }


                        if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                        {
                            returnValue.AppendLine($"{powershell.Streams.Error.Count} errors: ");
                            foreach (var err in powershell.Streams.Error)
                            {
                              returnValue.AppendLine($"{err.ToString()}");
                            }
                        }

// this will give me The term 'Disable-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

                        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                        command = new PSCommand();
                        command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
                        command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create("Disable-Mailbox -Identity patatem -Confirm:$False"));
                        command.AddParameter("Session", result[0]);
                        powershell.Commands = command;
                        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                        var mailBoxes3 = powershell.Invoke();

                        foreach (var item in mailBoxes3)
                        {
                            returnValue.AppendLine(item.ToString());
                        }

                        // check the other output streams (for example, the error stream)
                        if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                        {
                            returnValue.AppendLine($"{powershell.Streams.Error.Count} errors: ");
                            foreach (var err in powershell.Streams.Error)
                            {
                              returnValue.AppendLine($"{err.ToString()}");
                            }
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(returnValue);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I guess that it is due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: Should that not give me a permission type error?  Running the powershell by itself works fine.

Comment: AFAIK you get this message also if you don't have permission to run a cmdlet.

Comment: Well that seems to give much better results.  i switched accounts to run the c# (with more permissions) and I get none.  Good to know you get that error if you don't have permissions.  Thanks, MatSnow.  Put that as an answer and I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The term 'Disable-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

If the user attempting to run the `Disable-Mailbox`-cmdlet has insufficient permissions to disable a mailbox ([RBAC](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/01/13/use-powershell-and-rbac-to-control-access-to-exchange-server-cmdlets/)), this nonspecific error message is issued.

Run your code with sufficient permissions and it should work.

TechNet article: [Understanding Role Based Access Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298183(v=exchg.160).aspx)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  That error message implies the cmdlet is not imported/doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Error messages are often not as helpful as they could be. Maybe the cmdlet doesn't even get loaded with insufficient permissions.

Comment: Once @MatSnow gave me that tip, i switched accounts with permissions and the error went away immediately.