# Disable an exchange mailbox using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-restapi

I am trying to disable an exchange mailbox from C# code. Is there any way or API to do so by C#. I have tried with Powershell.

Comment: was there any output from Powershell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run Disable-Mailbox Powershell in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474426/unable-to-run-disable-mailbox-powershell-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It is not clear what code is used for disabling a mailbox. Moreover, there is no output recieved.

Comment: @JohnB I solved the problem with your help. Sure it's the duplicate of the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net version of my project is 4.0 and I was using the System.Management.Automation.dll file that support only .Net version 4.5. Now, I changed the ddl file that supports the .Net 4.0 version and it's working now.